# Compare changes among an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array where each element is a hash representing a simplified version of an entire Chess Board. I am trying to implement the [fifty-move draw rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty-move_rule) which states a draw can be claimed if in fifty moves, no piece has been captured and no pawn has moved.

In doing so, I'm trying to keep DRY and use code that I've already implemented for [another draw scenario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefold_repetition), which is currently working properly.

A new "snapshot" of the board is saved after each turn and looks like the following (after a pawn has moved from "a2" to "a4" on the first turn):

```
board_snapshot = [{
"a1"=>"Rook", "a2"=>nil, "a3"=>nil, "a4"=>"Pawn", "a5"=>nil, "a6"=>nil, 
"a7"=>"Pawn", "a8"=>"Rook", "b1"=>"Knight", "b2"=>"Pawn", "b3"=>nil, 
"b4"=>nil, "b5"=>nil, "b6"=>nil, "b7"=>"Pawn", "b8"=>"Knight", 
"c1"=>"Bishop", "c2"=>"Pawn", "c3"=>nil, "c4"=>nil, "c5"=>nil, "c6"=>nil, 
"c7"=>"Pawn", "c8"=>"Bishop", "d1"=>"Queen", "d2"=>"Pawn", "d3"=>nil, 
"d4"=>nil, "d5"=>nil, "d6"=>nil, "d7"=>"Pawn", "d8"=>"Queen", "e1"=>"King", 
"e2"=>"Pawn", "e3"=>nil, "e4"=>nil, "e5"=>nil, "e6"=>nil, "e7"=>"Pawn", 
"e8"=>"King", "f1"=>"Bishop", "f2"=>"Pawn", "f3"=>nil, "f4"=>nil, 
"f5"=>nil, "f6"=>nil, "f7"=>"Pawn", "f8"=>"Bishop", "g1"=>"Knight", 
"g2"=>"Pawn", "g3"=>nil, "g4"=>nil, "g5"=>nil, "g6"=>nil, "g7"=>"Pawn",
"g8"=>"Knight", "h1"=>"Rook", "h2"=>"Pawn", "h3"=>nil, "h4"=>nil, 
"h5"=>nil, "h6"=>nil, "h7"=>"Pawn", "h8"=>"Rook"
}]
```

In pseudocode, I'm thinking of implementing this fifty move rule check by creating a method which looks at the previous fifty board snapshots to see if the amount of `nil` values are the same (no piece captured) and if so, somehow looking to see that each of the Pawns are on the same square.

I've found a way to compare two boards to see if the `nil` values are the same:

```
board_snapshot[index].values.count(nil) == board_snapshot[index + 1].values.count(nil)
```

However, I'm still having trouble coming up with a way to iterate over 50 board "snapshots" to run this test on each one. Also not sure how to iterate over the 50 "snapshots" to ensure that no Pawn has moved.

If it would just be easier to implement this rule by creating a "counter" which resets when a piece is captured and when a Pawn is moved let me know, I was trying to be efficient and utilize code that was already around.

Comment: Your condition seems to be easier to falsify (counter + reset) than to verify (check last 50 board positions), so why make your life harder than it needs to be?

Comment: If you are going to add a computer opponent at any point, such solution would be terribly inefficient. I propose you do something way simpler - keep the last 3 hash codes for the threefold repetition rule and a counter for the fifty-move rule.

Comment: Another option is to go a different route and keep a list of command moves/actions, e.g., you'd know if a pawn moved by checking the commands. A capture would be represented by a command so you'd know if something had been captured.

Comment: Why do you need to iterate over 50 positions (I think that is the accurate terminology for your "snapshot", by the way.) to see if any piece was captured? Can't you just compare the present position with the position 49 steps back?

Comment: @sawa That's an interesting idea. So maybe see if the current position and the position 50 moves ago have the same `nil` spaces and same amount of Pawns?

Comment: You're not checking against a position 50 moves ago, you're checking the previous 50 positions--you have to know if a pawn was moved at any time in the 50 moves. How the state is materialized from those commands isn't strictly relevant, e.g., a "move" command whose target is a pawn could update the materialized state to indicate "a pawn has been moved", same with capture, in addition to capturing board state. It's more or less CQRS/eventing. And checking against 50 commands seems less than checking 64 board positions, although good hashing might make that issue go away.

Comment: @ndn The only issue I see with that is that threefold-repetition need not occur in consecutive turns. So board 20, board 31, and board 45 could be the same, triggering the rule. Am I understanding your comment correctly?

Comment: @scobo, then it is even more so that you should just save the hash codes (all of them, not just the last 3).

Comment: @ndn Ok then I guess I'm confused as I don't know what you mean by "hash codes". I'm relatively new to Ruby.

Comment: @scobo, it's not a Ruby specific thing (even though you can call `a_hash.hash` to get the code). It's basically an integer, which should uniquely identify a given state. [Wiki on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Comment: could you provide a test case of hashes that pass and a test case of hashes that fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @sawa has the right idea in the comments.  You only need to check that the Pawns are in the same position as they were 50 moves ago (since pawns can't move backwards, they can't move in one snapshot and be returned in the next)

```
board_snapshot.last.delete_if{|_,v| v != "Pawn"} == board_snapshot[-50].delete_if{|_,v| v != "Pawn"}
```

Similarly (and using your suggested code)

```
board_snapshotlast.values.count(nil) == board_snapshot[-50].values.count(nil)
```

Since pieces can't be added to the board, you don't need to worry about a piece disappearing in one move and reappearing in the next move.